# How to use group by to get multiple result set? grouping on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a table named as product which contains following data

```
pid            brand     color      

1              sony      white
2              casio     gray
3              xoxo      blue
4              samsung   white
5              mvc       silver
6              sony      gray
7              xoxo      red
8              samsung   silver
9              mvc       white
```

I need to get total count of products belongs to each brand & color. So i wrote 2 different queries.

```
Select count(pid) as total from products group by brand;
Select count(pid) as total from products group by color;
```

This works fine. But since my product table data is huge, I think its better if I can achieve this by a single query. Is it possible?

Comment: The question is somewhat confusing. When you say " get total count of products belongs to each brand & color" do you mean to get the counts separately or group brand first and then group by color then get the count?

Comment: Ok i will make it clear. I need count separately. ie. total count of products belongs to each brands & total count of products belongs to each color. Not the combination of the brand & color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply have the `UNION` of these two queries:

```
( SELECT 1        AS groupType
       , brand    AS grp
       , count(*) AS total
  FROM products 
  GROUP BY brand
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT 2        AS groupType
       , color    AS grp
       , count(*) AS total
  FROM products 
  GROUP BY color
)
ORDER BY groupType
       , grp
```

If you want the number of products for every brand-color combination, you should have the table grouped by these two fields:

```
SELECT brand
     , color
     , count(*) AS total
FROM products 
GROUP BY brand
       , color
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt here.  What is the advantage of using union over using 2 separate queries? Will it result in better performance? Actually brand & color I mentioned in this example are product attributes. In my actual table there are 6 attributes totally. So which approach will be better? A union query of all 6 queries or 6 individual queries?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using with statements, but this is not available in MySQL at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: This still wouldn't really give you a useful result set. You'd get just as many rows as the original table, that happen to have a count for the brand and color of that row in there. You'd have to then add a group by and you'll probably have an even more expensive query than just running the selects separately.

Comment: Actually not: the over() operator makes it equivalent to writing the two queries separately. But again, not available in MySQL.

Comment: While the values will be correct, you will still have a row for every product coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how huge your table actually is, it might be cheaper to get the totals for brand/color combinations first and store them to a temporary table, and then query the temp table twice to find the final totals by each criterion.

That is, something like this:

```
-- create a temporary table (omitted)

INSERT INTO temp_table (brand, color, total)
SELECT brand, color, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM products
GROUP BY brand, color

SELECT brand, SUM(total) AS total
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY brand

SELECT color, SUM(total) AS total
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY color
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
count(*) over (partition by product), 
count(*) over (partition by color)
from table
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL has partition.

Comment: @PMV: you are right, it's one of the few DBMS that doesn't support window functions

Answer (score 0):

```
select brand as `group`, count(pid) from products group by brand
union all
select color as `group`, count(pid) from products group by color
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping separately by two different columns results in two fundamentally different queries, so from the database's perspective, it's easier to run them separately. I'd look into creating two indexes (one on brand, one on color) to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT col_1, SUM(col_2), SUM(col_3) FROM table_name GROUP BY(col_1)";
```

Comment: add count at place of sum. this is just a general query i just saw with my project which can be applied any where